# sed command is replacing the replaced text?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am writing a bash script to rename icons. Specifically I am trying to change "icon-close-m" to "icon-close icon-size-medium" in HTML files. (though it could contain any substring besides "close", as noted by the `[a-z]` in the line below)

It works when I run this command from the command line:

```
sed -i -e "s/\(icon-[a-z]*\)-m[^e]/\1 icon-size-medium/g" ./app/index.html
```

Result:

```
icon-close icon-size-medium
```

But, when I run it from the script it changes it to this:

```
icon-close icon-sizeedium
```

Here is an example of text that should change:

```
<span class="icon-close-m"></span>
```

Should become:

```
<span class="icon-close icon-size-medium"></span>
```

It appears to be going through and replacing the `-m` *in the new replacement, after the initial replacement*. It is only doing this when the command is implemented in a bash script. I have not seen this happen before and I haven't seen any similar issues on SE/SO. Note that this command is not inside of any sort of loop.

Comment: Sure thing @steeldriver. Just edited. As far as I can tell, it goes through and adds `icon-size-medium` to the string. because *that* string has the letter e followed by -m, I believe it is replacing it because it matches the regex requirement.

Comment: I wonder if you have some stray control characters in the `sed` expression in the script?  You would get that result if the replacement text was `/\1 icon-size-m^H^Hedium/` where `^H` is a literal backspace character.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's a good call. How can I check for/remove stray control characters?

Comment: The simplest would be to just _retype_ the command in the script. Otherwise, it would depend on your editor. You could also use `od -a` on the script to see if you can spot any odd characters.